# Android Jetpack Compose Architecture: why it is not advisable to pass ViewModel directly to Screen as its argument/parameter?

Tags: architecture, android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I am trying to undersdand Android JetNews application which is provided as the canonical best practice architecture example application. Specifically - each screen has 3 files/classes: Route / ViewModel / Screen. E.g. Interests view contains those 3 files plus one additional component - those files can be accessed https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/interests and the whole application is accesible in the highe level of this repository.

One can see that InterestsViewModel https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/interests/InterestsViewModel.kt contains the event-handlers that can be assigned to specific events:

```
fun toggleTopicSelection(topic: TopicSelection) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        interestsRepository.toggleTopicSelection(topic)
    }
}
```

Of course - screen have many components and they can raise such events and handlers should be assigned to them. E.g. there is list if topics in this example and the user than toggle each topic to select/deselect as interesting/uninteresting. This can be done from the screen and that is why the screen should be able to call `toggleTopicSelection` and assign to the even of some UI component. So, one can logically expect that one should pass `InterestsViewModel` to the `InterestScreen` as an argument (i.e. their respective instances, of course).

But the exactly opposite thing is happening in `InterestsRoute` https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/interests/InterestsRoute.kt :

```
@Composable
fun InterestsRoute(
    interestsViewModel: InterestsViewModel,
    isExpandedScreen: Boolean,
    openDrawer: () -> Unit,
    scaffoldState: ScaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
) {
    val tabContent = rememberTabContent(interestsViewModel)
    val (currentSection, updateSection) = rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(tabContent.first().section)
    }

    InterestsScreen(
        tabContent = tabContent,
        currentSection = currentSection,
        isExpandedScreen = isExpandedScreen,
        onTabChange = updateSection,
        openDrawer = openDrawer,
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState
    )
}
```

There is `rememberTabContent` that receives `InterestsViewModel` and that constructs some UI Composable components and assigns `InterestsViewModel.toggle...` handlers to their events. But otherwise InterestsScreen is not receiving InterestsViewModel?

Why is that? My sense is that entire `InterestsScreen` should have access to the `InterestsViewModel` and use its event handlers as necessary. There may be many places when screen is willing to send the updates of the state and this can be done through `InterestsViewModel` event handlers only (which call into respective repository futher). As it stands now (when the developer is invited to avoid passing `ViewModel` as an argument to the `Screen`), the architecture requires to carefully and painfully isolate every smallest component that can require the call into `ViewModel` event handlers and assemble such components in respective `remember...` functions (e.g. `rememberTabContent`) (than can receive ViewModel safely). Such isolation seems to be counterintuitive and painful. E.g. if one wants to add another call to event handler (that changes state) then one needs to bring up such code from the `Screen` and isolate into `remember` function and completely regroup its code and screen composition tree. No freedom to work and use `InterestsViewModel` freely.

**So - is there some explanation whether to pass or not ViewModel to the Screen as an argument. And such passing is not advisable then how to understand such guideline?**

Comment: One of the reasons why one would not want to pass the whole VM into composables is because then they are harder to `@Preview` and also harder to test in isolation compared to passing in just the needed state and callbacks. With the latter when you `@Preview` or test the composable you can just pass in some specific state and change the callbacks (in previews you can just pass a no-op `{}` for callbacks) and you are done. With a VM parameter you would have to pass in a whole fake VM just to be able to preview a composable.